# WordPress Custom Page URL rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress

i have custom page on wordpress which is accessible in following way:

```
domain.com/custom-page/1
```

how could i achieve following url pattern:

```
domain.com/custom-page/1/Title-of-Page-Content
```

or

```
domain.com/custom-page/1-Title-of-Page-Content
```

it seems like after "custom-page" other then integer value is not acceptable.

Note:
i have tried .htaccess way and by adding following code in theme/functions.php

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('custom-page/([^/]*)/([^/]*)?$','index.php?pagename=custom-page&_id=$matches[1]&title=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you creating the page using pages in wordpress? or is this a static page that lives in a folder outside the theme?  
wordpress gives you the option to build the url using parent/child hierarchies in pages. So all you would need to do is create a page called custom-page, hit publish, and then create another page called 1,  select from the "parent" dropdown menu under "page attributes" and then follow the same step for 3rd child page.  so in the end you have a url that looks like /custom-page/1/Title-of-Page-Content

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the Admin area of Wordpress, go to the Settings pop out menu. There is an option for Permalinks. Go there and select the pattern you'd like for your page slugs. I think the specific one you want to select is Post Name, according to what you are saying.